# mongo or sql tagging system

Tags: mysql, mongodb, tagging

I have a tagging system in my mind and here are my ideas,

1, I can make a mongodb database and add tags to an embedded field and index them all

2, I can use SQL for it, I can add the tags as a new entry to a table

3, I can create another collection on mongodb and do it like this

for example the tag is "chicken", this is the document

```
tag:"chicken",
id:"1200000,32555,8787888888"
```

the tag is the chicken, the id is other documents that relate with the chicken, I think those systems will give me lots of headaches. especially the first one. Do you have any tagging system ideas for my need ?, by the way, there will be more than one million different tags and searched this tagging system before opening this question,

thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to achieve this in mongo, i would create documents that look like

```
{
    tag: "chicken",
    ids : [ 12345,23456,34567 ]
},
...
```

then two indexes, one on "tag" and a multikey index on "ids" 
(http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#multikey-indexes).

```
db.tags.ensureIndex( { "tag": 1 } );
db.tags.ensureIndex( { "ids": 1 } );
```

depending on what queries you need to do there may be value in creating a compound index on both attributes.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#compound-indexes

e.g.

```
db.tags.ensureIndex( { "ids": 1, "tag" : 1 } );
```

1 million tag docs will not be an issue, I have similar collection with ~3m docs each having on avg 15 items in the multikey index and performance is excellent (from dev vm).

i hope this helps

Comment: thank you, I think we don't need to index ids, because we will not search for those, is your multikey like this one ? "tags":"asd,bsd,csd,dsd,fsd,gsd" ?

Comment: Multikey index can be on arrays. So would be "tags" : [ "aaa","bbb",..]

Comment: By indexing the ids you would be able to find the tags for a specific id or ids for a specific tag

Comment: I was thinking to add another embedded array for that purpose, so when a page is served I can make it with one query

Comment: sorry, there is a part I don't understand, is your 3 million documents' schema look like my first option or third option ?

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB is great for such tagging thanks to how it indexes lists. Consider a document like this one:

```
{_id: 42, name: "someName", tags: ["chicken", "parrot", "hovercraft"]}
```

If you add an index for `tags` field, you can efficiently perform queries like this:

```
{tags: "chicken"}
```

This query will find all documents that contain `"chicken"` in its `tags` list - that is, all documents tagged with `chicken` tag.

I'm not sure if this is what you meant in your first point. If it is then I don't understand why it gives you headaches.

Comment: there will be too many tags, it will take long time to index even in background indexing, but thank you for your answer